# Standardize a data structure in Python

Tags: python, oop, data-structures

If i'm using this structure through many different files/scripts
When changes are necessary, how can I just change in one place instead of having to change it in every file.

```
u = contents
incomingUrl = urlparse(u).query
ok = parse_qsl(urlparse(u).query, keep_blank_values=True)
def eventType(ok):
      try:
            return o[0][1]                                                         
        except (IndexError):
            pass
def networkName(ok):
        try:
           return ok[1][1]
        except (IndexError):
           pass
def networkEmail(ok):
        try:
            return ok[2][1]
        except (IndexError):
            pass
def channelName(ok):
        try:
            return ok[3][1]
        except (IndexError):
            pass
def sceneType(ok):
        try:
            return ok[4][1]
        except (IndexError):
            pass
def sceneUrl(ok):
    try:
       return ok[5][1]
    except (IndexError):
       pass
def sceneTag1(ok):
    try:
       return  ok[6][1]
    except (IndexError):
       pass 
def sceneTag3(ok): 
    try:
       return ok[7][1]
    except (IndexError):
       pass
def scenePrice(ok):
    try:
       return ok[8][1]
    except (IndexError):
        pass
def scenePriceDnom(ok):
    try:
        return ok[9][1]
    except (IndexError):
       pass
def networkAvatar(ok):                                                             
    try:        
        return ok[10][1]
    except (IndexError):
        pass `
def sceneLat(ok):
    try:
        return ok[11][1]
    except (IndexError):
        pass
def sceneLong(ok):
    try:
        return ok[12][1]                                                       
    except (IndexError):
        pass
def timestamp(ok):
    try:
        return ok[13][1]
    except (IndexError):
        pass
```

How can i objectify i guess that structure, change it one place and bring it into many places.
I use classes and methods all the time....is this just a class but how would i bring it in another file and use it?? kinda confused on this one.

### EDIT:

Example data coming from source

```
 http://webservice.com/log?eventType=youtubeScene&networkName=loqootv&networkEmail=sirthomas@gmail.com&sendToChannel=loqootv&sceneType=youtubeScene&
      sceneUrl=https://webservice.s3.amazonaws.com/tv_702ef50873f7270323b7285c28aae078837b7ecb.mp4&sceneTag1=youtube_gdata_player&
     sceneTag3=&sceneTip=&sceneTipDnom=&networkAvatar=BTC&timestamp=http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/59e9efab5fcf64b3d391641f5?&d=http%3A%2F%2Fwebservice.com%2Floqootv%2FLTVlogo.png&size=2048
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use common code in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118008/how-can-i-use-common-code-in-python)

Comment: I use modules and all the time, im jus stuck on how i would situate that particular structure

Comment: So you have this schema, and you're rewriting this throughout each of your independent Python scripts? There's a principle of Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself . If you're copying this code from script to script, you're violating that principle. You should bare minimum be importing this as a module once per script. There's a lot of repetitiveness here, however, but i's not readily apparent to me how I would factor that out immediately, while keeping that independent of the code that's using it. Decorator would perhaps do the exception handling.

Comment: so you just want to know where in your filesystem to place your code so that it can be imported into any of your python programs?

Comment: no i understand that, i want to know how to factor that code in one module and use as it just the same in other files. would the whole thing be a function or a class. im not really getting how to make that particular code DRY.

Comment: Boy when I first saw this, I did not intend to answer it. It suckered me in with the decorator option. :)

Comment: thanks that you did, you made me read and learn on decorators!

Answer (score 3):

To factor out the redundant code, I would write a decorator:

```
results = {} # This dict can map your API

def indexcatcher(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            results[func.__name__] = result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return inner
```

Then for each function:

```
@indexcatcher
def eventType(ok):
    return ok[0][1]

@indexcatcher
def networkName(ok):
    return ok[1][1]

@indexcatcher
def networkEmail(ok):
    return ok[2][1]

@indexcatcher
def channelName(ok):
    return ok[3][1]

@indexcatcher
def sceneType(ok):
    return ok[4][1]

@indexcatcher
def sceneUrl(ok):
    return ok[5][1]

@indexcatcher
def sceneTag1(ok):
    return  ok[6][1]

@indexcatcher
def sceneTag3(ok): 
    return ok[7][1]

@indexcatcher
def scenePrice(ok):
    return ok[8][1]

@indexcatcher
def scenePriceDnom(ok):
    return ok[9][1]

@indexcatcher
def networkAvatar(ok):
    return ok[10][1]

@indexcatcher
def sceneLat(ok):
    return ok[11][1]

@indexcatcher
def sceneLong(ok):
    return ok[12][1]                                                       

@indexcatcher
def timestamp(ok):
    return ok[13][1]
```

And after defining each function and wrapping it with a decorator that logs the results for a particular item and handles the possible index exception:

```
def get_results(ok):
    eventType(ok)
    networkName(ok)
    networkEmail(ok)
    channelName(ok)
    sceneType(ok)
    sceneUrl(ok)
    sceneTag1(ok)
    sceneTag3(ok)
    scenePrice(ok)
    scenePriceDnom(ok)
    networkAvatar(ok)
    sceneLat(ok)
    sceneLong(ok)
    timestamp(ok)
    return results
```

And now your results dict should provide you with a mapping, and this should be backwards compatible with your current API.

```
results = datamodule.get_results(ok)
```

And now you're down to 55 lines (about 1/4th of which are blank lines) from 70 (what, 83 if there were blank lines separating them?), and the new functions are a lot more readable, so that's a bit of a maintenance gain as well.

Now if you're importing this from every file, you'll have to maintain a consistent API, and if you're doing that quite a lot, you need to really consider costs and benefits of changing that.

Comment: thanks for ya time and your thoughts, yes constantly changing the api is something I do frequently, and its a concern with production nearing, It must stop. this will surely help

Comment: I'm concerned that you're defining your data location by index. I would much prefer a semantic structure that would let me access the data by keywords. Then you don't even need these functions, you could use a single function to access the data and provide you with the information you intend to retrieve.

Comment: can you expound on that... access the data by keywords.. the data comes in the form or a url with parameters attach. can you point me in the direction of literture or terms to search

Comment: Well it sounds like you have no control over the data source, but you might wrap it all together into a consistent API for your own purposes. I'll see if I can show you a succinct way to do it.

Comment: i edited the qs and added an example piece of data coming from source...if it helps any

Comment: I don't see it helping, but I've finished wrapping the data in a dict for you that would be returned by a single function while still supporting your current API (while you migrate?). You could do it another way as well, but I think this is as much as I can do at the moment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46130/discussion-between-sirvon-and-aaron-hall)